# Get max date for each year from list of dates

Tags: group-by, sql-standard, date

Need to get max date for each year from list of arbitrary dates:

```
date         year
=================
1/10/2013    2013
3/26/2013    2013
4/20/2012    2012
9/10/2012    2012
5/6/2011     2011
```

So with a working query, using the above data, the correct result would be:

```
maxdate     year
=================
3/26/2013    2013
9/10/2012    2012
5/6/2011     2011
```

Our database is proprietary, supporting only ANSI-SQL, no fancy extensions. 
Tried using `group_by`, but it's retrieving all dates for each year, not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that I am missing something, but you should be able to get the result easily using the `max()` aggregate and a `GROUP BY`:

```
select
  max(date) maxdate,
  year
from yourtable
group by year;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9666/1)

Comment: I was grouping by date, that was the issue, ty.